# Action reaction pair rapidity or time delay

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

How much rapid is action reaction force ?

Suppose i have a rocket of 10kg dry mass and 10kg reactive mass. On launching, 5 kg of reactive mass is burnt. And i get a thrust of 200 N. What will be the acceleration of the rocket? Take g=10m/s^2

Is the thrust enough to lift off the rocket? Is 200N reaction force acts on the total weight of the rocket that is 20kg? or 15kg ?